# How to implement IF statement, in my online powershell command

Tags: powershell, rename, brackets

I am running a powershell command in my batch file to remove brackets from foldernames, but it renames all folders in the path, and it gives me an error if the foldernames doesn't contain brackets.

I would like it to run on a specific folder, and I would like it to check if the name even contains brackets before running. If there is no brackets in the name, it should do nothing.

Hopefully keeping it a one line command

I have searched the internet, but I just can't find the solution.

The command:

`powershell -command "Dir -Path e:\test | rename-item -NewName { $_ -replace '\[','_' -replace '\]','_'}"`

The batch file is run automatically with some parameters, and I am getting the exact name of the directory I want to rename, from the parameters. (i.e. start.bat param1 param2)

I have tried to implement the IF statement, but I just can't figure it out.

The reason for removing the brackets, is because, the module "remove-itemsafely" cannot handle names with brackets. This module puts the files in the Recycle Bin, instead of deleting them permanently.

Hope someone can help me, thanks.

Comment: why are you using PoSh in a BAT/CMD file? is there some need for that? things are usually easier if you _don't_ mix languages like that.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey well, I am trying to move over from batch to powershell, but its mostly just a hobby thing. So I mostly google for what I need. I started the batch for a simple task, since I feel comfortable with that, but I wasn't sure how to move files/folders into the recycle bin without having several lines of code. So I just found a simple solution with the powershell module remove-itemsafely, and went with it. And it works very well. Also the issue I had was solved without this rename command, I just needed to add the parameter -literalpath.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. [*grin*]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest using this PowerShell command:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path e:\test -Filter "*`[*`]*" | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace '\[','_' -replace '\]','_' }
```

The back-ticks are there as escape characters.

Comment: Ah, thank you @harrymc .. It's funny how simple things can be, and here I used several hours to try and find that solution :) I actually looked at the -filter option, but was stuck in another mindset... thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for only folder names, thus `-Directory`.
If you want to also rename the directories deeper down in the hierarchy, inside `c:\test\anotherFolder\` for example, just add `-Recurse` to the `Get-ChildItem` command.

Although it could be assumed, you didn't specify that the brackets were going to be in an open, then closed order.  Nor that both were necessarily going to exist in folder names.
This regex pattern `'\]|\['`, which is saved into the `$rgx` variable, will match `]` OR `[` so it'll catch all instances.
The `\` is the escape character.
The `|` is the OR character.
We can use the pattern both for the filter (`Where-Object`) block, and name replace matching (`-replace`) block.

Lastly, you seem to want to be able to run it from a batch file so I made sure it works that way.

```
powershell -command "$rgx='\]|\['; Get-ChildItem -Path 'c:\test' -Directory | Where-Object { $_.name -match $rgx } | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.name -replace $rgx,'_' }"
```

Btw, the `;` is the command separator character.  First the `$rgx` variable will store the pattern string, then the one-liner will be executed.

Comment: Thank you for this very nice explanation. It helps a lot on understanding the various options in your solution. I am sure I will look back on this, for future endeavors 